# Quick Search Box : can't get SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement custom suggestions for qsb. I have added `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS suggestion_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, suggest_text_1 VARCHAR(50),suggest_intent_data INTEGER)` as suggestions table. The output of of `intent.getDataString()` is only `content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests`. I'm real confused here. I thought it would give the value of `suggest_intent_data`. How can I get the content of column `suggest_intent_data` from the `intent`?

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), (intent.getDataString()));
    };
```

**From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html**

> Define the data for each suggestion inside the
>   SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA column of your suggestions table.
>
> Provide all necessary data information for each intent in the
>   suggestions table by including the SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA column
>   and then populating it with unique data for each row. The data from
>   this column is attached to the intent exactly as you define it in this
>   column. You can then retrieve it with with getData() or
>   getDataString().

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests" //yeah, I thought this was causing the problem too. But after removing this line no change. 
    android:searchSuggestThreshold="1"
    android:searchSuggestSelection=" ?"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not selecting `suggest_text_1` `suggest_intent_data` from the table while performing query. Adding those fixed it.